# Look who just showed up!

Tags: riddle

Be sure to keep watch,
a tough guy just walked in.
He's got a reputation in these backwards parts,
and he could deliver a real beating.
If there's a lady around, he'll just hold his cup.
I think, for the most part, he's just a mixed-up fool.

*Each line matches the correct answer, but the title's irrelevant. None of the clues is literally applicable; it's a little more cryptic.*

Comment: If the clues where literally applicable, Sir Henry Morgan would have been a perfect fit :/

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Hah, not bad! Even ends up on the rum :P

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is

> strap

Be sure to keep watch,

> A watch strap

a tough guy just walked in.

> As in a strapping lad

He's got a reputation in these backwards parts,

> strap is parts backwards

and he could deliver a real beating.

> To give someone the strap

If there's a lady around, he'll just hold his cup.

> A bra strap, though possibly also works with jockstrap

I think, for the most part, he's just a mixed-up fool.

> Anagram of sprat, though prat is more common these days, hence the "most part".

Comment: hold his cup -> jockstrap

Comment: "If there's a lady around, he'll just hold his cup" could refer to a bra strap and a cup size.

Comment: Thanks, @NeedAName, I edited jockstrap in within the 5 minutes :)

Comment: Excellent work! As Aggie mentions, I had intended line 5 as a bra, but jock strap works equally well.

Comment: And here we present the only case ever where jock strap and bra work interchangeably.

Comment: I'm guessing a jock strap's efficacy does not depend on the presence or otherwise of a lady, so I would venture that bra strap is probably a better answer.

Comment: I've edited the 5th line answer/explanation to include both.

Answer (score 13):

I take my chance with:

> Jon Snow (from Game of Thrones)

Be sure to keep watch,

> Jon works on the Night's Watch

a tough guy just walked in.

> He is quite the tough guy beating wildings and white walkers

He's got a reputation in these backwards parts,

> Reputation for being a bastard but also because he is a great fighter

and he could deliver a real beating.

> He is a great fighter

If there's a lady around, he'll just hold his cup.

> You are not allowed to sleep with women in the watch, so he'll just hold his cup...

I think, for the most part, he's just a mixed-up fool.

> You could said that he is a mixed-up fool because he wants to help the wildings but he is from the night's watch.

Comment: Nice guess and good application, but it's a bit more cryptic. I'll add a note to the main question. +1

Comment: You know nothin', TroyAndAbed!

Comment: TroyAndAbed knowing noooothing!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a

> cake

Be sure to keep watch,

> Take care, don't drop it.

a tough guy just walked in.

> I guess "tough" is a word that can be used to describe the consistence of cake.

He's got a reputation in these backwards parts,

> Cake is said to be very tasty and ofc many people like it.

and he could deliver a real beating.

> Thinking of films when people throw cakes at faces.

If there's a lady around, he'll just hold his cup.

> Maybe some referrence to drinking coffee/tea etc,

I think, for the most part, he's just a mixed-up fool.

> A cake is the result of mixing together ingredients.

Comment: Good try, but most of the clues here feel pretty stretched, getting better towards the end.

Answer (score 2):

> Alcholol

Be sure to keep watch,

> Dont drink too much

a tough guy just walked in.

> Alcohol can be dangerous.

He's got a reputation in these backwards parts,

> Not sure: after many drinks you forget parts of the day before and people have to tell you afterwards.

and he could deliver a real beating.

> Hangovers suck

If there's a lady around, he'll just hold his cup.

> ?Ladys drink from cups guys from bottles?

I think, for the most part, he's just a mixed-up fool.

> Alot of people mix alcohol.

Comment: Maybe one can simply hit somebody's head with a bottle (of wine,...) :D

Comment: There's some good leads, especially with lines 3, 4 and 6! Unfortunately the others don't match as well and it's not the intended answer. Good try!

Comment: @Samsthere whiskey was my original guess

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a guess at:

> Caitlyn Jenner, formerly known as Bruce Jenner

Be sure to keep watch,
a tough guy just walked in.

> College football player, and Olympic athlete

He's got a reputation in these backwards parts,
and he could deliver a real beating.

> Married a Kardashian, the surname being famous for their "backwards parts". Also won Gold in the Decathlon at the Olympics.

If there's a lady around, he'll just hold his cup.
I think, for the most part, he's just a mixed-up fool.

> Now he is the lady around, with his own "cups". Mixed-up in that he "*dealt with gender dysphoria since youth*", hence the gender transition.

Comment: Interesting direction and a good attempt, but unfortunately it doesn't fall into place as well in the earlier parts. Nice try!